# aiohttp task upload file(s)

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Objective: to receive the file, the file list, from the mold and process them in task's.
However, solving this problem, a problem, a file descriptor is closed when transmitting it to the task. It's so conceived or is it a problem?
I do not want to deal with dual-boot by the javascript files using asynchronous aiohttp.

**server side cut**

```
@app.post('/files', name="files_post")
async def files_post(request):
    # read data file
    data = await request.post()
    print(data)

    # filename for save
    filename = data['filename'].filename

    # get fd
    iofile = data['filename'].file

    path = app.static_path + '/{}'.format(filename)

    # check work task --> fucken problem?>
    app.loop.create_task(app.savefile(filename=filename,iofile=iofile, data=data))

    return web.Response(body=b"ffs suxx upload..")

    with open(path, "wb") as fout:
        while iofile.closed:
            buf = iofile.read(buffer_size=1024)
            fout.write(buf)
    print("File {} success upload".format(filename))
    return web.Response(body=content,
                        headers=MultiDict(
                            {'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="{}"'.format(filename): filename}))
```

**html side cut**

```
<strong>Upload</strong>
<form method="post" action="/files" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <strong>Choise files: </strong> <input type="file" name="filename" multiple>
    <input type="submit" name="sender" value="Send" />
</form>
```

**task cut**

```
async def savefile(self, filename, iofile, ptosave=None, data=None):
    if isinstance(iofile, io.BufferedRandom):
        path = os.path.join((ptosave or self.static_path_upload), filename)
        fin = fout = None
        print('[TASK] From task:', iofile)
        print("[TASK] -->", data['filename'].file.closed)
        print("[TASK] --> File upload closed: ", iofile.closed)
        try:
            iofile.readable().type(iofile)
        except ValueError as err:
            print("[TASK] readable: {}".format(err))
            return

        # back
        if not iofile.closed:
            try:
                with open(path,"wb") as fout:
                    buf=iofile.read(1024) # read 1024 bytes
                    fout.write(buf) # write buf ~ len(buf) bytes
            except IOError as err:
                print("SAVENAME: ", err)
            finally:
                if fout:
                    fout.close()
            print("File {} upload".format(filename))
```

**debug messages cut**

```
[MIDDLEWARE - database] [ Engine creating ] <aiomysql.sa.engine.Engine object at 0x8084790b8>
Method: POST
Path: /files
Cookies: {}

[MIDDLEWARE - database] [ Engine creating ] <aiomysql.sa.engine.Engine object at 0x80848ea90>
<MultiDictProxy('filename': Field(name='filename', filename='8.png', file=<_io.BufferedRandom name=10>, content_type='image/png'), 'sender': 'Send')>
[TASK] From task: <_io.BufferedRandom name=10>
[TASK] --> True
[TASK] --> File upload closed:  True
[TASK] readable: I/O operation on closed file
```

Comment: What is `if fout: fout.close()` doing? Your indentation is a bit of a mess too,

Comment: @PadraicCunningham close outfile file descriptor (local for save `stream`)) if get exception with context.

Comment: the idea of a context manager is that even if there is an exception your file will be closed

Comment: Let me see if I'm understanding the question correctly: You want to take a list of files uploaded in a HTML form and save them on the server. Once a file is transferred completely, you want to provide feedback to the user. -- Is that correct?

Comment: @JashandeepSohi I want to handle downloading files asynchronously task loop.event
[/ Files ---> loop.create_task (savefilename) * count (files)] <---

Comment: @Spouk if i understood your question, you want to process uploaded files asynchronously and  want to provide client feedback that files accepted for processing and as an when files are processed you want to push client the file names which are processed successfully right?